TL431 - LTspice simulation
EXPLANATION OF THE APPLICATION
I am trying to make the current limiting circuit that I saw in the TI document.

In picture 1, I set up a simple transistor circuit below. Ib (base current)= 0.9 mA, Ic (collector current) = 170 mA. Vref is around 1.7 V so TL431 is not active.

In Picture 2, I added TL431. I increased the IC current to 275 mA and made Vref 2.8 V, that is, I provided a minimum reference voltage of 2.5 V for the TL431 to become active. However, when I measure the TL431's cathode current (green trace), I see it as 0 A.

In Picture 3, I think that it may not be fully active and increase the Ic current to 386 mA. This time, although the Vref is around 3.88 V, the TL431's cathode current is still around 0 A and I can increase Ic of Q1 as much as I want and the TL 431 does not become active at all.


QUESTION

Why is TL431 not activated even though I increased the Ic current of Q1 which makes the Vref (3.88 V) well above the 2.5 V for the TL431, where do I make mistake?

Picture 1: Simple transistor circuit

Picture 2: The circuit with tl431

Picture 3: The circuit with increased Ic current


I doubt TI would publish this design for a 0.5A current limiter. Pls cite link.  You should consider a design for a 50 mV drop at max current. not 2.5V.

I told you once before in the same question you deleted.  The current gain must be greater than the resistor ratio implied by hFE = Rb/(Re's) (for Vout =~1/2 Vin).  All the answers support this.  You must choose the worst case beta or hFE to ensure it works. Then put adequate power dissipating components in place.  Using a method that detects <= 50 mV on Rs at max current would be more efficient.

I am trying to make the current limiting circuit that I saw in the TI document Not quite. You're trying to simulate the circuit, not make it. I would advise to actually assemble it from physical parts and do measurements. Make sure you're following the same operating conditions as in the application note, especially with regards to the supply voltage. Please cite the application note and figure number you took this circuit from.

The TL431 needs 2.5 V from the Ref pin to the anode pin to regulate. The voltage from the Ref pin to the anode pin is the same as the voltage across R1. So R1 needs 2.5 V across it for the TL431 to regulate.
To get 2.5 V across R1, there needs to be 2.5/R1 = 2.5/5 = 500 mA through R1. This current is equal to the emitter current of Q1.
The maximum collector current through a 2SC2411 is 500 mA. This, in itself makes the design questionable. However, let's proceed.
The current gain for a 2SC2411 ranges from 82 to 390. If the gain were 82, this would mean that to achieve 500 mA through the emitter, you would need approximately 500/82 mA through the base or approximately 6.1 mA.
That 6.1 mA needs to flow through R3, which is 3000 ohms. To get that current requires 6.1 mA x 3000 ohm = 18.3 V across R3.
The minimum power supply voltage to ensure 18.3 V across R3, 0.7 across the base-emitter junction of Q1, 2.5 V across R1 and 2.5 V across R2 is 23.7 V
Now, with 18.3 V from collector to base of Q1 and 0.7 V base to emitter, Q1 will have 19 V collector to emitter, with 500 mA of current. It will thus dissipate 9.5 W, and burn up because the maximum power rating of the 2SC2411 is only 200 mW.
The first thing you need to do is replace your transistor with a power transistor. Unfortunately, this will in all probability lower the current gain. You could try an integrated Darlington transistor such as a member of the TIP1xx series, or you could use two discrete transistors in Darlington configuration. You will need a heatsink.
Then, depending upon the gain of your power and/or Darlington, you may need to reduce the size of R3. Then your circuit might work (with sufficiently high power supply voltage).


Let's say I ensured the values in your calculation with Vb=5.7 V, Ve= 5 V, 2.5 V on R1 and 2.5V on R2 approximately, how can I calculate the Ika (current from cathode to anode of tl431) ?

If Vb=5.7 V, then you are not using a Darlington, so let's assume you are using the TIP33C which has a minimum \$\text{h}_{\text{FE}}\$=20.
You will need in worst case a base current of 500 mA / 20 = 25 mA. If you use a 11 V supply, as in the last image of your question, and the base is at 5.7 V, you will have 5.3 V across R3.
To get 25 mA through a resistor with 5.3 V across it, the resistor can be no more than 5.3 / 0.025 = 212 \$\Omega\$. You could probably get away with a 220 \$\Omega\$ resistor, but designing for worst case, choose a 200 ohm 1/4 watt resistor.
This will provide 5.3 V / 200 ohms = 26.5 mA.
How much of this will go to the base of Q1 and how much to the cathode of the TL431 is impossible to say, and can change from one moment to the next. It depends on how much base current the TIP33C draws in order to provide 500 mA emitter current. And that depends on the actual current gain.
Since the maximum current gain of the TIP33C is about 100 (see below) and since the emitter current is the collector current plus base current, the minimum base current the TIP33C will need is about 500 mA / (1 + 100) \$\approx\$ 4.95 mA. So, the maximum current through the cathode of the TL431 would be approx 26.5-4.95 = 22.05 mA. So, if R2 is your load, and you are hoping to provide it with exactly 500 mA, this circuit has the shortcoming of providing 22.05 or about 4.4% more. You will get a more accurate control of the current through R2 if you change design to use a Darlington pair. The trade-off is that the base voltage at the base will need to be closer to 6.3 or 6.4 volts.
Note: the maximum current gain may vary with the collector current. It is not specified for 500 mA, so the gain of 100 is the approximate maximum.

Thank you so much.I understand my mistake . I have a related question. Let's say I ensured the values in your calculation with Vb=5.7 V, Ve= 5 V, 2.5 V on R1 and 2.5V on R2 approximatelly, how can I calculate the Ika (current from cathode to anode of tl431) ? @Math Keeps Me Busy

On the 5 volt supply
The TL431 needs 2.5 volts between control terminal and pin 2 to begin activating but, this can never be achieved because, you only have a 5 volt supply and, that supply is split between two equal value resistors (5 Ω each) and the upper BJT. In other words, it's impossible to get 2.5 volts between the control pin and pin 2 because the BJT will certainly "lose" some of the 5 volts between its collector and emitter. The amount that the BJT "loses" is somewhere in the region of 0.7 volts to 1 volt so, you see, it's impossible to get the TL431 to activate.
On the 8 volt or 11 volt supply
To get 2.5 volts across either 5 Ω resistors requires 500 mA to flow through them. That cannot be argued against of course. But, the problem is that you need to get the BJT to supply 500 mA and, it might have a hFE of (say) 100. That hFE means 5 mA has to flow through the 3000 Ω resistor. For that to happen you need 15 volts across it but, you only have an 11 volt supply so, how can 15 volts ever be across that resistor? Impossible. You would need a supply in excess of 20 volts for that to happen.

You could make this work by replacing the transistor with a TIP121 Darlington (with a large heat sink).
R3 has to be low enough to ensure enough base current for the Darlington, in addition it has to supply at least 1mA for the TL431 to regulate. 3k ohms will work with 10V, but it is too high for 8V. 1.5k ohms is low enough to work at 8V.

Here is the sim with a 1kΩ bias resistor, givng a regulated 500mA constant-current.

